# Is there a way to override style from Semantic-UI with style from Styled-Components in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, semantic-ui, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

I'm building a small project in ReactJS and I would like to use Semantic-UI (as a main theme of my website) and override some parts of it with Styled Components (like if it was some custom CSS).

When I'm trying to import them on the same component, I've noticed that Styled-Components will use some of the style I wrote but not all of it (like text-size or some margin).

**EDIT**
Here's the way I've tried to implement them in my component:

```
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Grid, Form, Segment, Button, Header, Message, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { StyledRegister } from '../styles/StyledRegister';

class Register extends React.Component {

...

render() {    
 return (
   <StyledRegister>
     <Grid textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
       <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
         // Here's continue the long code of my register page including form ect...
       </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    </StyledRegister>
```

Do any of you have an idea if it's possible, and if so, is there proper way to do it ?

Comment: Could you show how you tried it to do?

Comment: Question has been updated with my file, let me know if you need further informations.

Comment: How does your `StyledRegister` component looks like? I will give you an example how I do it usually.

Answer (score 0):

An example with the custom adapted statistics component of semantic ui:

```
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { StyledStatistic } from "./styledStatistic";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledStatistic>
        <StyledStatistic.Value>5,550</StyledStatistic.Value>
        <StyledStatistic.Label>Downloads</StyledStatistic.Label>
      </StyledStatistic>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Statistic } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const StyledStatistic = styled(Statistic)`
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;

  &&& > .value {
    color: red;
  }
  &&& > .label {
    color: green;
  }
`;
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-mestorf-go410